# yii2 assign default image when image file is left blank

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I want to assign a default image when 'n_img_path' is left blank.
Here is my actionCreate function.

```
    public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new NurseTbl();
    $model->scenario = 'createrule';

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'n_img_path');

        $model->n_img_path= $model->n_nic.'.'.$image->extension;

         if ($model->save()) {
            $image->saveAs( 'uploads/nurses/'.$model->n_img_path);

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->n_id]);


        }



    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Default image is inside 'uploads/nurses' folder.I want path of default image to be saved in my database.

Answer (score 0):

For that column in database, assign default image path as default value.

In your case

for **n_img_path** assign  **uploads/nurses/default.png** as default value